# Insufficient parallelization with Task library - possible solutions?

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, threadpool

A .Net Framework 4.7 program iterates over a list of 50,000+ items and processes them, like so:

```
var taskList = new List<Task<bool>>();

foreach (var item in itemList)
{
    taskList.Add(Process(item));
}
Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

The executable runs on a single virtual box with 8 virtual processors, and takes 3-4 hours to run.

Based on timestamp analysis, it appears that processing is spread over these 3-4 hours with a couple hundred milliseconds between the items' processing start times.

Dynatrace is showing logical threads capped at around 25 during execution.

What would be the best way to achieve a higher degree of parallelization, to bring down the total processing time?

Not looking at a major overhaul at this point; only at getting Tasks to spin up more efficiently.

Thank you.

Comment: What does the `Process` method do? Is it making web requests? Reading from a hard disk? Does it do a lot of processing using the CPU and memory? The answer to your question will depend on this.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Thanks for your comment. Process() fetches data from a SQL Server database at various points in the method, executes some logic, and makes a few database updates and inserts.  The same database tables are involved for each item being processed, although updates happen conditionally.  The program doesn't appear to be CPU- or memory-intensive, from what I can see in Dynatrace.

Comment: Most of your time is probably spent waiting for reads and writes at the database layer, then. Assuming you're calling the appropriate `*Async()` functions and using `await` appropriately, you probably won't get much value from parallelism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've shown doesn't appear to be doing any parallel processing. If `Process` is truly async then you're probably getting a high level of concurrency from it, but not parallelism.

A shorter version of what you're doing now looks like this:

```
var taskList = itemList
    .Select(item => Process(item))
    .ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(taskList);
```

If `Process` spends a lot of time CPU-bound, you could introduce parallelism like this:

```
var taskList = itemList
    .AsParallel()                    // Do it in parallel
    .Select(item => Process(item))
    .ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(taskList);
```

You can play with different degrees of parallelism to arrive at a number of concurrent threads that seems to provide the best throughput for the work you're doing, like this:

```
var taskList = itemList
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(50)      // 50 concurrent threads
    .Select(item => Process(item))
    .ToArray();
Task.WaitAll(taskList);
```

But if `Process` is spending most of its time waiting for results to come back from an asynchronous operation, it probably won't make a significant difference to make it run in parallel threads. In that case you'll need to investigate what's making your individual operations take so long. For example, maybe you're running into a connection pool limit on network requests to the same destination. Maybe a REST service is throttling your requests. Or maybe your hard drive is thrashing. Hard to know without understanding the details.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply.  Appreciate the suggestions.  We'll try them out and investigate further.  As far as how long the operations take - 98% of the items were processed in under 50ms.  92% were processed in under 20ms.  There were only a few that took 200-400ms.  But if I look at the timestamps when each item was loaded from the database (which is the first step in Process()), there are 200+ms between each timestamp, which is what's adding to the total processing time.

Comment: @pikkabird: That sounds odd. It's probably worth doing a little profiling to see if you can identify where the most time is being spent. It's possible that there's something you wouldn't suspect that's actually taking a lot of time and you could get a quick win from it.

Comment: Beyond that, I know you don't want to do a major overhaul, but I'd guess you'd see a huge performance boost if you can batch some of those operations. For example, if you could load all the data you're going to need for 50 (or 500) items out of the database in one query, then figure out all the inserts and updates that should be required for all of them and use a bulk insert/update to make all those changes at once, you could greatly reduce the number of round-trips.

Comment: In the end, we found out that Process() wasn't truly async.  With that resolved, we got the results we wanted.  Thanks again for your input.